# Expose MongoDB on Kubernetes with StatefulSets outside cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I followed the guide in the following link: 
http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets.html

and set up a mongo DB replica set on Kubernetes with StatefulSets. So far so good, but how do I expose that static hostnames outside the cluster so that I can access them from a Google instance for example?

If I use the IPs of the nodes it will work fine but those can change anytime (upon pod failure and restart with a different IP etc.)...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the answer is present in the StatefulSet Basics documentation section [Using Stable Network Identities](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/abstractions/controllers/statefulsets/%20https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#headless-services):

> The Pods’ ordinals, hostnames, SRV records, and A record names have
>   not changed, but the IP addresses associated with the Pods may have
>   changed. In the cluster used for this tutorial, they have. This is why
>   it is important not to configure other applications to connect to Pods
>   in a StatefulSet by IP address.
>
> If you need to find and connect to the active members of a
>   StatefulSet, you should query the CNAME of the Headless Service
>   **`(nginx.default.svc.cluster.local)`**. The SRV records associated with the
>   CNAME will contain only the Pods in the StatefulSet that are Running
>   and Ready.
>
> If your application already implements connection logic that tests for
>   liveness and readiness, you can use the SRV records of the Pods **`( web-> 0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local, web-1.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local)`**, 
>   as they are stable, and your
>   application will be able to discover the Pods’ addresses when they
>   transition to Running and Ready.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest taking a glance at the service docs to make sure you're familiar with what is happening:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

> A Kubernetes Service is an abstraction which defines a logical set of Pods and a policy by which to access them - sometimes called a micro-service.

With that in mind and the guide you're using, note the following:

> You can tell this is a Headless Service because the clusterIP is set to “None.” Other than that, it looks exactly the same as any normal Kubernetes Service.

So what you've created is a headless service(no load balancer or exposed IPs)

So **instead** of the configuration given for a headless service:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: mongo
      labels:
        name: mongo
    spec:
      ports:
      - port: 27017
        targetPort: 27017
      clusterIP: None
      selector:
        role: mongo
```

What you actually want is:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: mongo
      labels:
        name: mongo
    spec:
      ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 27017
        targetPort: 27017
      selector:
        role: mongo
```

Very subtle but you'll notice that the `clusterIP` property no longer exists.

I also prefer to specify the protocol, for completeness, even though TCP is the default.

Answer (score -1):

You need to expose the service (svc). The pod by definition would as you said have different IP's.

In the example mentioned at https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/petset/ , you will notice the service definition.

```
foo.default.svc.cluster.local
         |service|
         /       \
| pod-asdf |    | pod-zxcv |
```

This is what you need to concentrate on.The service once tied to DNS would give you a stable lookup.
By the way , StatefulSets is the maturing of earlier Pet Sets.

Comment: This isn't really helpful. The question is "how do I expose the service" and your answer is "you need to expose the service." The image you linked to is from the section "what is a PetSet?" which doesn't say much either.