# Unable to access mongodb-replicaset with local pymongo client

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, pymongo

I have deployed mongodb on Kubernetes using mongodb-operator (verison: 1.9.2). The ReplicaSet consists of 3 instances: 1 primary and 2 secondary. I am able to access the ReplicaSet from any of given Kubernetes pods but if I try to do the same from the local machine  with pymongo client I am getting error as shown below. Can anyone suggest the reason for such behavior?

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongodb-2.mongodb-svc.mongodb-new.svc.cluster.local:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known,mongodb-0.mongodb-svc.mongodb-new.svc.cluster.local:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known,mongodb-1.mongodb-svc.mongodb-new.svc.cluster.local:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 610292f511a5060cc91f8a11, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongodb-0.mongodb-svc.mongodb-new.svc.cluster.local', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongodb-0.mongodb-svc.mongodb-new.svc.cluster.local:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)>, <ServerDescription ('mongodb-1.mongodb-svc.mongodb-new.svc.cluster.local', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongodb-1.mongodb-svc.mongodb-new.svc.cluster.local:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)>, <ServerDescription ('mongodb-2.mongodb-svc.mongodb-new.svc.cluster.local', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongodb-2.mongodb-svc.mongodb-new.svc.cluster.local:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)>]>
```

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text

Comment: I am extremely sorry i am new to stackoverflow can you please provide relevant documentation so that i reformat the question

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have found 2 similar problems: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264108/name-or-service-not-known-when-using-dockerized-flask-mongodb) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264595/mongoimport-in-docker-compose-gives-me-cannot-start-service-error) Did any of them help you?

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikołajGłodziak. I looked into these but it didn't help to solve my problem.

Comment: I have found this link helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730112/exposing-mongodb-on-kubernetes-statefulsets-to-external-world

Comment: @stevesteel is your problem now resolved? If yes please post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted Community wiki answer for better visibility.

As [steve steel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13866186/steve-steel) has mentioned in the comment, he has found the solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730112/exposing-mongodb-on-kubernetes-statefulsets-to-external-world):

> I have found this link helpful: [Exposing mongodb on kubernetes statefulsets to external world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730112/exposing-mongodb-on-kubernetes-statefulsets-to-external-world)